# Mbp early 2011 stuck at white screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

Can anybody help me witha fix about mbp early 2011 stuck at white screen after boot. I have tried to boot in safe mode before by pressing power button and shift key which it actually work but when i shutdown mbp just to on it the next day the problem still persist. Please any help will be appreciated [image]

Answer (score 1):

No guarantee this will solve it, but it *might* help:

- [Reset PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063)
- [Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295)